# Set value properties into general view

Tags: ember.js

Is possible to link data by handlebars to Ember.view ? Like Ember.Select with valueBindig.

My attempt:

```
{{#each models}}
<li>{{id}}</li>
{{/each}}

// -> 1,2,3 (this works fine)

{{view App.TimelineView valueBinding="models.id"}} //this doesn't work



App.TimelineView = Ember.View.extend({

    tagName: 'div',
    attributeBindings: ["value"],
    value: null,

    didInsertElement: function(){ 

    console.log(this.value) 
    ...
    })
```

Console log: ---> null

but I need [1,2,3]

Answer (score 0):

Supposing `models` is an array, `models.id` is accessing the `id` property of the array itself, not of each element. What you probably want is to map models to ids.

Define the following property on the controller which `models` is defined on:

```
modelIds: Ember.computed.mapBy('models', 'id')
```

And then use `modelIds` in the template instead of `models.id`.

Also, you should access properties `this.get`-style, not directly (in `didInsertElement` for example).

Comment: This didn't help for me. I think template side is correct, but ember.view need some modification to understanding what a valueBinding is. Variable "value" is still "null", handlebars doesn't fill it. And this.get-style return the same result (this.controller.get('modelsId');)

Comment: You should be accessing `value` in the view, my suggestion was to use `this.get('value')` instead of `this.value`. Additionally, you have to find models in the `model` hook on the route, because `store.find` returns a promise. See http://jsbin.com/OJUTuyu/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

You are not accessing `value` correctly. The right way of doing that is as below. There were some more errors in there that I fixed.

```
App.TimelineView = Ember.View.extend({
    tagName: 'div',
    didInsertElement: function() { 
       console.log(this.get('value'));
    },
)};

{{#each models}}
   {{view App.TimelineView valueBinding="id"}} 
{{/each}}
```

The context within the loop is this, which represents the current element of the iteration, so you want 'this.id' or simply 'id'.

Addition: If you want to get a list of all the `id`s at once as an array (as opposed to item-by-item), you can do the following:

```
App.MyController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
   allIds: function() {
      var ids = this.get('content').getEach('id').reduce(function(accum, item) {
         return accum.push(item);
      }, []);
      return ids;
   }.property('content.@each.id');
});
```

Comment: Hmmm, it is interesting. This works, but I found another problem. I would like get a list of all ids of model for "valueBinding", not one by one at {{each}}. It is possible?

Comment: Sure. See the addition to this answer

Comment: Hi again :) I tryied this list of ids, but my call of this method is wrong. My use: (in didInsertElement()) var list = this.allIds; console.log(list) --> undefined. The function I insert to App.TimelineController

Comment: `this.allIds` will try to get the value from the view (where it does not exist. You will have to do `this.get('addIds')`, which will delegate to the controller.